# TeamCity Conditional Maven Releases

Tags: maven, teamcity

I am pretty new to TeamCity and was hoping to get some best practice advice. We are using the Maven-Release plugin to do our releases and it works great, however we have a situation where we would like to have releases both off the trunk for test teams and then branch when we feel the codebase is stable enough for a proper release candidate. Ideally I'd like to have a single TeamCity release project, that by default will do a 'test release' off the trunk unless a build parameter is passed (e.g. project.release.type = branch) and then TeamCity will execute a different build configuration which will perform a mvn release:branch instead of a prepare.

Basically, can I conditionally execute TeamCity build configurations & how? Otherwise is there a suggested was to cater for the above scenario other than having multiple TeamCity release projects.

Cheers